# Internal link stucture of a wiki/page ranker

Tags: mediawiki

I want to get the internal link structure of and also apply page ranker to a wiki in the Wikimedia format. I have an extremely large html file dump which is the history.xml file. This includes all the internal link in [[]] but also has every revised version of all pages. I am wondering if there is a way to extract the internal link structure. I know the Wikipedia dumps come with this in a separate file but I only have the history.xml

Answer (score 0):

Dump the [pagelinks table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pagelinks_table) of the wiki (or a new wiki you have imported the xml dump into).